# DNS unable to resolve *.co.uk domain names

Tags: dns, windows-7

I am encountering very strange problem, I'm unable to resolve any *.co.uk domain names. Other domain names ending with .com, .net etc are fine.

- Pinging domain names like bbc.co.uk gives `Ping request could not find host vantagefx.co.uk. Please check the name and try again` straight away
- I'm using a company PC on a network (we don't use proxies) and my colleagues on the same network can resolve *.co.uk fine
- Ok, maybe it's my PC's DNS cache, I then tried rebooting, running `ipconfig /flushdns`, none helps
- If I ping the the IP number directly it replies fine (eg: 212.58.253.67 for bbc.co.uk)
- I've checked my C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file and no rules related to *.co.uk exists there
- I've cross checked my network connection settings with my colleagues and they're all matches

Is there anything else I can do to debug this mysterious problem? I'm on Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to resolv anydomain.co.uk domain name via several DNS server, for example via Google public DNS: `nslookup vantagefx.co.uk 8.8.8.8`. It could help investigate the issue.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't know nslookup can be used against another DNS server. The problem mysteriously goes away after a night, I think it's  a problem with DNS caching mechanism on my PC / our network router

Comment: do an `ipconfig /flushdns` in an elevated command prompt